# RSA encryption fail on older Android device (4.0.3 in this case)

Tags: java, android, security, encryption, rsa

im pretty new to android development and i have the following method for encryption data using RSA(2048b):

```
public byte[] encryptData(String base64) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    byte[] dataToEncrypt = base64.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")); //lenght == 90
    try {
        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(rsaKeys.getPublicModus(), rsaKeys.getPublicExpo());
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPublicKeySpec);

        //default providers
        //4.0.3 - BC (BouncyCastleProvider)
        //4.4.2 - AndroidOpenSSL
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt); //this throw exception

        return encryptedData;
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

This block of code working on Android 4.4.2 like a magic. Problem comming with Android 4.0.3 where its always end with exception:

```
com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: input too large for RSA cipher.
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RSACoreEngine.convertInput(RSACoreEngine.java:115)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RSABlindedEngine.processBlock(RSABlindedEngine.java:95)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.encodings.PKCS1Encoding.encodeBlock(PKCS1Encoding.java:184)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.encodings.PKCS1Encoding.processBlock(PKCS1Encoding.java:132)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCERSACipher.engineDoFinal(JCERSACipher.java:467)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1106)
```

Im confuse whats wrong (data length and keysize is on both device same). I will be grateful for any clue. Thanks.

---

My RSAKeys class contains simple constructor and get/set for each field:

```
private BigInteger publicModus, publicExpo;
private BigInteger privateModus, privateExpo;
```

Im using this method for RSA key generation:

```
@SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
public RSAKeys generateRSAKeys() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

        // Pullingout parameters which makes up Key
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(publicKey,
                RSAPublicKeySpec.class);

        RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrivKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(
                privateKey, RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

        rsaKeys = new RSAKeys(
                rsaPubKeySpec.getModulus(), rsaPubKeySpec.getPublicExponent(),
                rsaPrivKeySpec.getModulus(), rsaPrivKeySpec.getPrivateExponent());

        return rsaKeys;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

---

I edited my code for using same message to encrypt `base64 = "plain text";` and same RSA keys on both devices. Without any progress. Still getting error on device with Android 4.0.3.

Devices:

- HTC Desire 610 - Android 4.4.2
- HTC One V - Android 4.0.3

Comment: Either `dataToEncrypt` is too large (despite your claim it is 90 bytes long) or the modulus is too small (despite your claim that is 2048 bits in size). Another very unlikely possibility is that your Android 4.0.3 device has a very strange default platform charset like UTF-32. By using the no-args `String.getBytes()` method you leave yourself at the mercy of platform-specific defaults. Always specify the charset.

Comment: @Tomas how does your implementation of `getPublicModus` looks like?

Comment: @JamesKPolk was try using base64.getBytes(UTF-8) but doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

try to specific both algorithm and provider

```
 // example how to generate key pair 
class MyKeyPair {

    private static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";
    private static final String PROVIDER ="BC";
    private static final int STRENGTH = 2048;

    private PrivateKey _privateKey;
    private PublicKey _publicKey;
    public PublicKey getPublicKey {return _publicKey;}


    public MyKeyPair() {
        generateKeyPair(STRENGTH,RSA,BC);
    }

    private void generateKeyPair(int keyLength, String algorithm, 
                                                String providerName) {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = 
                          KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(algorithm,providerName);
        keyPairGen.initialize(keyLength);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
        _privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        _publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
    }
}
```